# Angular - (File) input works irregular on file select

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Angular v 9.0.7

i have this input in my html which is gets triggered by the button:

```
<input #file (change)="importFile($event)" accept="audio/*, image/*, video/*" hidden type="file">
<button class="msg-npt-btn msg-npt-fl-icon" (click)="file.click()"></button>
```

it works for the first time i select a file but after that importFile() get called every second or third time if i select another file.

```
    importFile(event) {
    alert("import"); //test
    if (event.target.files.length == 0) {
      console.log("No file selected!");
      return
    }
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is example how to load images may will it help.

```
importFile(event): void {
  alert('import'); // test

  const reader = new FileReader();

  if (event.target.files.length === 0) {
    console.log('No file selected!');
    return;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  reader.onload = ((r) => {
    this.selectedFile = r.target.result;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thx but I’ve got the same and it works. My problem is, after the first invoke of importFile() I have to select a file 2-4 times in order to invoke it again. That’s why I’ve added the alert to check it.